# pandastable blank space removal

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

[image: Side by side tables with blank space]

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the extra blank space around a pandastable in tkinter. The issue I'm having is basically that the entire dataframe renders correctly and then there appears to be a blank column to the side of the table and a blank row below it. But, looking at my dataframe it only has 2 columns and 5 rows as shown. Is there a way to make the actual frame object fill the entire space instead of this blank?

```
summaryframe = ttk.Frame(normal_window, height = 100, width = 100, relief = 'ridge')
colors = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
g_final_diff_string = []
for i in gfinal_diff:
    g_final_diff_string.append('{}%'.format(i))
g_final_diff_string.append(str(gpoints))

gluc_df = pd.DataFrame([colors, g_final_diff_string]).T.rename(columns = {0: 'Parameter', 1:'Value'})

g_pt = Table(summaryframe, dataframe=gluc_df)

g_pt.show()


summaryframe.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


ketsummaryframe = ttk.Frame(normal_window, height = 100, width = 100, relief = 'ridge')
k_final_diff_string = []
for i in kfinal_diff:
    k_final_diff_string.append('{}%'.format(i))
k_final_diff_string.append(str(kpoints))

ket_df = pd.DataFrame([colors, k_final_diff_string]).T.rename(columns = {0: 'Parameter', 1:'Value'})
print(ket_df.columns)
k_pt = Table(ketsummaryframe, dataframe=ket_df)

k_pt.show()

ketsummaryframe.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Edit: Included the code sample shown above. Some of the code is just structuring the dataframe. The pandastable section is both of those with "_pt" Also, added context, these frames both sit under objects that are 300px wide each. I think that "pandastable" object is taking up the full width but the table is only taking up the 100px that it is assigned?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is better if you share a snip code to get help and as proof of effort.

Comment: Added that above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! For those still curious...

Turns out I was overriding the width option elsewhere in the code.
The way to hardcode the width of a table is:

```
g_pt = Table(leftframe, dataframe=glucose_cap_df, width = 165)
```

The width property helps to remove the grey outlined box I had surrounding my table. Unfortunately if you're using an input into the table of variable width you'll probably need to set that width with a variable.

Further word to the wise, if you're interested in your table growing as the user expands the window make sure to place your table inside a frame with properties like this:

```
frame.pack(fill = 'both', expand = True)
```